# Consecutive Count on Record Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number, gaps-and-islands

I'm working on a data structure with list of positive or negative result for each person.

Sample data (id is an identity):

```
id      person  result
1       1       0
2       1       1
3       1       1
4       2       1
5       2       0
6       1       1
7       1       0
8       2       0
9       2       0
10      2       0
```

With this I would like to count the maximum number of `consecutive` `result = 1` for each person. The result in this sample would be

```
person  max_count
1       3
2       1
```

I have tried using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY)` like this

```
SELECT person, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person, result ORDER BY id) AS max_count      
FROM TABLE
```

but it gives me an `accumulative` count instead of `consecutive` one.

What should I do to perform a consecutive count? Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: `gaps-and-islands`. What is the version of SQL Server? I think I can write the final query, but one thing is unclear. Why `max_count` for person  `1` is `2`? Based on your sample it should be `3`, no? Rows with IDs: `2,3,6`. Rows `4,5` are for different person, I think they should be ignored, shouldn't they? Or, are you interested in a strict "consecutive" sequence, where IDs **must** be in a sequence without any gaps? If you add few more rows to your sample that explain different variants, it would help to understand what you need.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov you're right. I've made a mistake on the question. Will correct that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like classic `gaps-and-islands` problem.
Examine intermediate results of each CTE in the query below to understand what is going on.

**Sample data**

I added person `3` with two sequences of positive results, so that we could find the longest sequence.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id int, person int, result int);
INSERT INTO @T (id, person, result) VALUES
(1 , 1, 0),
(2 , 1, 1),
(3 , 1, 1),
(4 , 2, 1),
(5 , 2, 0),
(6 , 1, 1),
(7 , 1, 0),
(8 , 2, 0),
(9 , 2, 0),
(10, 2, 0),
(11, 3, 0),
(12, 3, 1),
(13, 3, 1),
(14, 3, 1),
(15, 3, 1),
(16, 3, 0),
(17, 3, 1),
(18, 3, 1),
(19, 3, 0),
(20, 3, 0);
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_RowNumbers
AS
(
    SELECT
        id, person, result
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY ID) AS rn1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person, result ORDER BY ID) AS rn2
    FROM @T
)
,CTE_Groups
AS
(
    SELECT
        id, person, result
        ,rn1-rn2 AS GroupNumber
    FROM CTE_RowNumbers
)
,CTE_GroupSizes
AS
(
    SELECT
        person
        ,COUNT(*) AS GroupSize
    FROM CTE_Groups
    WHERE
        result = 1
    GROUP BY
        person
        ,GroupNumber
)
SELECT
    person
    ,MAX(GroupSize) AS max_count
FROM CTE_GroupSizes
GROUP BY person
ORDER BY person;
```

**Result**

```
+--------+-----------+
| person | max_count |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 |         3 |
|      2 |         1 |
|      3 |         4 |
+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: In your sample data, person 1 has only 2 consecutive positive result but in your query result, it says 3?

Comment: @Kim, The query allows to have gaps in IDs when determining the sequence. For person `1` the rows with IDs `2,3,6` form a sequence of rows with `result=1`.

Comment: I see... didn't notice the edit he made on the question. I was still looking at the result where P1 = 2.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Brilliant! Thanks man. The use of GroupNumber did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

by using Case and SUM we can achieve the above result

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id int, person int, result int);
    INSERT INTO @T (id, person, result) VALUES
    (1 , 1, 0),
    (2 , 1, 1),
    (3 , 1, 1),
    (4 , 2, 1),
    (5 , 2, 0),
    (6 , 1, 1),
    (7 , 1, 0),
    (8 , 2, 0),
    (9 , 2, 0),
    (10, 2, 0)
    select 
    person,
    SUM(CASE WHEN RESULT = 1 then 1 else 0 END) 
     from @T
    GROUP BY person
```

Comment: That doesn't fulfil the consecutive requirement. Eg, for person 1, if there is 0 between 1s. That would return sum of 1s without taking the zero into consideration.